# Laravel 5.4 cannot view image in public storage in blade

Tags: php, image, laravel-5.4

I am having trouble getting Laravel to display an image that is in public storage.

Each user has their own folder and I want to display their profile image.

I've searched everywhere for an answer and I'm doing everything suggested and it still won't show the image.

- I've run `php artisan storage:link`
- I've made sure that `Options FollowSymLinks` is set in Apache
- The image exists in the public storage folder
- I've set permissions of the user folder and image to 777

I have tried the following and the image is not shown

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $userfolder. '/profile_image.png') }}">
```

If I go to the URL for the image in the browser, I get a 403 error message.

I don't know if I'm missing anything from here

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
...
```

Comment: 403 would indicate a permissions issue - does Apache's user have permissions to read that directory?

Comment: Simple issue to solve.... You cannot load files from the storage directory because it is not publicly accessible! You have to put the images in the public directory.

Comment: @mquinn, The image and folder has permssions set to 0777.

Comment: @mic, I've run php artisan storage:link which should make the image accessible

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure:

`$userfolder = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' .$extension;`

NOT:

`$userfolder = $request->file('imagePath')->storeAs('public', $fileNameToStore);`

The 1st code will store file as `filename.ext` , 2nd code will store file as `public/filename.ext`

using `src="{{ asset('storage/'.....` will give you a path with `public/ folder` already so using `src="{{ asset('storage/'.' $userfolder'` with the first code in your controller will show image